# How to load django objects requesting DB once and do searches after

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Suppose I have a QuerySet of all db entries:

```
all_db_entries = Entry.objects.all()
```

And then I want to get some specific objects from it by calling `get(param=value)` (or any other method). 
The problem is, that In [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-do-not-return-querysets) of QuerySet methods it is said: `"These methods do not use a cache. Rather, they query the database each time they’re called."`.

But what I want to achieve is to load all data once (like doing `Select *`), and only after do some searches on them. I don't want to open a connection to the db every time I call `get()` in order to avoid a heavy load on it.

Comment: You can convert your queryset into normal python objects and do all the normal Python stuff. However, are sure this is a clever approach? Why are you paranoid about making a database call? Normally searches on the db level are much more effective. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/performance/#work-at-the-appropriate-level): "...the database can typically do things faster than Python can, which can do them faster than the template language can"

Comment: @Chris Provided doc is inappropriate: it is talking about abstraction layers. Of course if you do the same thing in lower layer, then it is faster (in the example on all cases there's 1 DB access; on slower case there's an additional `len` call). 
What if there is 1 DB call vs 1000?
I care about this, because db is accessed not only by one function, but also by others and big load on it may cause issues.
RAM is always faster than storage DB, otherwise Django will not use [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) to **minimize database access**

Comment: Not fully sure whether I aggree. Django uses caching to fetch all data you need in one go (including functions like ```prefetch_related``` and ```select_related```) but not for modifiying queries. 1000 db calls vs 1000 python operations? Anyway, something like ```list(MyModel.objects.values('pk', 'field'))``` will give you a python ```list``` of ```dicts``` which you can manipulate.

Comment: @Chris Sure 1000 python operations will be faster than 1000 db calls! Thanks for your suggestion. Using this info I carried out fast tests and was ensured that my approach is right.  [code herte](https://gist.github.com/Serob/e462a341edaa291dfc6782a9cba3c5c4). On my PC (with quite fast nvme SSD) `test_db` worked 1.9 seconds and `test_ram` 0.2 in average (5 calls each). Almost 10 times improvement makes sense, isn't it? With slower SSD or HDD the difference will be bigger. 
This becomes more important when there are other parallel requests to db also, which can dramatically rise the time.

Comment: @Chris you can write your suggestion on `values()` as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Intersting information regarding the performance. Need to check that out in more detail in future projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `values` to convert your resulting queryset in an ordinary python list, which you can use to do searches etc., e.g.:

```
list(MyModel.objects.values('pk', 'field'))
```

`values` will fetch the queryset once.